# Printing to Excel Cells by Column in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

So the project I'm working on requires me to read in a CSV file, parse it and find desired columns, then print the desired columns to another worksheet. Part of my problem is that I'm learning VBA along the way, so there's gotta be something simple that I'm missing.
I've tried lots of different ways to print, none of which print in columns like I want. If there is a thread that has already answered this question, I'm sorry, but I can't find it.
So far, I've been able to read in the CSV file and store all of the information into a 2D array. here is the code for that:

```
i = 0 'This is the x value of the 2d array
'Populate the 2d array with the CSV File Data
Do Until csvFile.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = csvFile.ReadLine
    sArray() = Split(sLine, ";")
        For j = 0 To UBound(sArray)
            stArray(i, j) = sArray(j)
        Next j
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Right now, I'm at the part where I'd like to print the desired columns to the array. I'm attempting a test print just to make sure that I can do this before I start checking, so I'm using the single dimension array for testing instead of the 2D array.
Once I figure out how to print, then I'll run my 2d-array through an if-statement that will look for desired columns.

Here is my test code:

```
Dim o As Object
Set o = CreateObject("excel.application")
o.Visible = True
o.Workbooks.Add

    For r = 0 To UBound(sArray)
        o.Sheets("test").Range(o.Cells(3, 1).Address, o.Cells(3, r).Value = sArray(r)
    Next r
```

Instead I'm now being greeted by a runtime error '1004' "Application-defined or object-defined error' for the line in the loop.
I don't have enough experience or knowledge of VBA to know how to fix this. My experience is with Java and Python.

At the same time, how do I print an array to a column of cells? Am I doing this right?

Any help with this would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel can use the 2 dimensional array to assign values to the cells, but you'll need to Transpose (flip the dimensions) your array, `stArray`.

Assuming that `stArray` is size properly.

```
    o.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(stArray, 2) + 1, _
    UBound(stArray, 1) + 1).Value = o.Transpose(stArray)
```

Your code doesn't redim `stArray`.  If there are extra rows or columns then use your i and j variables to `Resize` the range.

```
    o.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(j + 1, i + 1).Value = o.Transpose(stArray)
```

If your wanted to iterate through each element of the 2 dimensional array:

```
    With o.ActiveSheet
        For rws = 0 To UBound(stArray, 2)
            For cols = 0 To UBound(stArray, 1)

                .Cells(rws + 1, cols + 1).Value = stArray(cols, rws)

            Next
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm working through the logic of your statement, so excuse me if this seems like an ignorant question:
Is there no way to run through a cells(i, j) = array(i, j) as I print?

Comment: I updated my answer.  You can do it but it is much slower.

Answer (score 0):

There are few easier ways to query/filter/aggregate external data in Excel without VBA.

For Excel 2010 and above, [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-a-column-of-text-Power-Query-5282d425-6dd0-46ca-95bf-8e0da9539662) should be the easiest and most .. powerful.

Another way is `Data` tab > `From Text` > `Delimited` > and enter `;` in `Delimiters` `Other:`.
After that you can delete the extra columns, add filters to the table, and use VBA for whatever can't be done with Excel. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840319.aspx

Also, there are few ways to use `SQL` to query/filter/aggregate external data:
http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/msquery-excel-text-files.htm

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a more automated solution. This is not a one time thing because we are a general contractor and this is for printing data from one of our printers.